# Unable to filter the data for the third relation

Tags: laravel, filter, relationship

We are getting latitude and longitude on the 3rd level due to which the filter in the below query is not working in Laravel

```
// Filters Form Nearest location with latitude and longitude.        
if ($request->latitude !="" && $request->longitude !="") {
    $list = $list->whereHas('partnerOutletPromotion', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->select(DB::raw("*, 6371 * acos(cos(radians('".$request->latitude."')) * 
        cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians('".$request->longitude."')) + 
        sin(radians('".$request->latitude."')) * sin(radians(latitude))) AS distance"));
        $query = $query->having('distance', '<', 100000);
        $query = $query->orderBy('distance', 'asc');
    });
    return response()->json($list->get());
}

// model function
public function partnerOutletPromotion(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(PartnerOutlet::class, PartnerOutletPromotion::class);
}
```

Error message

[image]

Comment: show the error trace man!

Comment: added. pls check https://i.stack.imgur.com/heoAG.png

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your database is not in sync with your model. You should probably make a migration.